# I accidentally deleted the camera app: how to recover it?

Tags: installation, camera

Somehow I got into a mode where apps selected were intended for *deletion* .  I did not realize that and the camera app got deleted.  I have not made any changes since that happened. What can I do to either recover or reinstall the camera app?

This is a Xiaomi Redmi 8A running Android 9.  It is not rooted. As far as "how /when did it happen" I do not know more than this: somehow it ended up that ALL  applications were selectable with a white round circle and asking "DELETE apps" or something similar.  I had never seen that mode before (or since). I tried to get out of that mode but ended up with accepting the Camera that was selected and got deleted.

On and off I do connect Android Studio to the phone - for pushing a simple Ionic app to it. Does Android Studio have some mode that allows bulk deletion of apps on the phone?

Comment: This cannot happen so easily (camera app being a system app and immune from deletion). Is your device rooted? It would help which Android phone and Android version you have? What were you doing or what app were you using which uninstalled camera app? Is this the same camera app that came with your phone?

Comment: @Firelord I updated the question. I  do not even know _how_ to root the device.  The mystery mode I ended up in (no idea how)  was allowing me to select any or all apps of whatever kind for deletion. I tried to get out of that mode without any effect but did not de-select the Camera app apparently.  One thing is I have been using Android Studio for pushing a simple Ionic App. Could that have gotten into a strange mode?

Comment: I think you might have entered into Settings -> Apps -> clicked on Uninstall button, and then selected apps. Xiaomi devices come with *GetApps* app which allows installing apps/bloatware in your device. See if that offers your Camera app. Also, just to be sure have you ensured that Camera app was not *disabled*. Your device might offer an option to shows disabled apps somewhere.

Comment: Thanks : my phone seems to only have `PlayStore` and not `GetApps`

Comment: I just what to confirm that Camera app is indeed no longer in your system (that is, it is not disabled either). Can you install this app and search the term *camera*? This is a FOSS app hosted on a fellow mod's website. https://apt.izzysoft.de/fdroid/repo/io.github.muntashirakon.AppManager_377.apk

Comment: Wow this is a serious process to get installed. I have downloaded and went to directions and selected ADB over TcP. Now there are still  a number of steps. I'll have to come back to this.

Comment: Oh, no no. You don't have to bother with adb or root. It is needed for advanced functionality offered by the app. Ignore it, just search for Camera term in the app and see if your camera app is shown there.